# How do I link to an image with the new (early 2012) Facebook lightbox?

Tags: facebook

I love the new lightbox, but one thing I miss from the old lightbox was the ability to copy the URL directly from the addressbar of the current picture, to send someone to a page to see the picture with comments.

The new lightbox only shows the url as facebook.com. How do I get the URL to the new lightbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to link to the image lightbox, just right click the gear icon & click on copy shortcut /link.

[image: Link to the image lightbox]

To get a a direct hotlink to the image, clicking on the Gear brings up a Download option, so right click that to get the hotlink URL.

[image: Hotlink to the image]